# How many times has the Millennium Falcon been captured by the Galactic Empire?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

Does anyone know how many times the Millennium Falcon has been captured by the Galactic Empire?

Comment: In which continuity? Only Canon or are we talking Legends also?